# Running .NET4.0 project on other PC giving following error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Please suggest how can I fix this. My Application .NET framework version and Visual Studio .NET framework is the same.

`Problem signature: 
 Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
 Problem Signature 01:  snap (bacnet).exe
 Problem Signature 02:  1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 03:  53aa51ca
 Problem Signature 04:  Snap (BACnet)
 Problem Signature 05:  1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 06:  53aa51ca
 Problem Signature 07:  13
 Problem Signature 08:  b
 Problem Signature 09:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
 OS Version:            6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
 Locale ID:             1033`

Comment: You're missing a file?

Comment: Is this all the info there is? Also I see a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, this will rather be the problem than a .NET version issue.

Comment: What are steps you followed and you end up with this trace ?

Comment: Actually i have copy one the release folder from VS 2013 and just run the exe file, which uses System.Io also.

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies appear to be missing.

Check:

- The correct version of .net is installed on the target machine.  If
  your application targets 4.0 and the target machine has 4.0 client
  profile on it, this is also an issue. (Client profile is a subset of
  4.0 full)
- That all of your included/referenced dll's and other resources are included with your deployment to the target machine.